# Is C# System.Thread using the Win32 API?

Tags: c#, multithreading, winapi

Is the C# Mulithreading with System.Thread using the Win32 API or how is System.Thread working?

Comment: Somewhere deep below it will presumably access OS specific threading functionality, yes. What do you need to know this for?

Comment: Simple answer to the question is yes

Comment: @UnholySheep I was asked to implement multithreading in C#, using the Win32 API, so according to David Heffernan this is the case. 
So this should be fine

Comment: If you write C# code, you want to avoid using Win32 API directly unless you really need something that is not available in .NET framework.

Comment: C# provides its own methods to do these things. You don't have to mix Win32 and C#, and it's not recommended.For more details about use multithreading in .NET you could refer to the Doc:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/threading/threads-and-threading#how-to-use-multithreading-in-net. If you still wish to use .NET and Win32, you should use c++/cli.

Comment: Why would you need to use Win32 API? Surely the C# libraries already give you enough.

Answer (score 1):

System.Thread threads are Dot Net runtime managed threads which are different from native win32 threads.

C# or Dot Net managed threads are managed by the Dot Net runtime and when in a running state are backed by native threads. But there is no direct 1 to 1 correlation between the Dot Net runtime managed threads and native threads.
For example the native thread used to back a managed thread may be different on  when it resumes after a context switch